# Ant: Logging via Log4j

Tags: ant, log4j

My issue is to make ant logging in the way I need. So that I decided to use Log4j. As I has read from [this article](http://www.mail-archive.com/log4j-user@logging.apache.org/msg06574.html) I set the ANT_OPTS:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///d:/ant_dir/lib/log4j.xml
```

When I try to execute the build.xml by the command:

```
D:/ant_dir>ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener
```

I catch an error: **Class org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener could not be loaded because of an invalid dependency.**
The log4j.jar and log4j.xml are located in the ANT_HOME/lib directory.

I have been searching for a tutorial but found nothing. 
Can somebody, please, help me with an advice or give a useful link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. The problem was in log4j.jar. This file was corrupted. I have changed it and everithing is working now.